# Render PHP with jQuery instead of Handlebars?

Tags: php, jquery, handlebars.js

I have already in my software Handlebars in using, but I'm not so familiar with it, so it is possible to render a PHP file instead of Handlebars file?

The code is:

```
loadFormTemplate = {
    main: Handlebars.compile($('#load-form').html()),
    error: Handlebars.compile($('#form-error').html()),
    info: {
        formBox: Handlebars.getTemplate('formbox')
    }
};
```

Simple to edit name in *getTemplate()* of course. not works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery `.load()` function to load a PHP file.

More info: http://api.jquery.com/load/

```
$("#your_div").load("test.php");
```